# Formula that returns an array containing cells that meet a certain criterion, from a larger range of cells?

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to have a formula that returns an array containing cells that meet a certain criterion, from a larger range of cells?

For example, in the image below I want a formula that gets the IQR of Asphalt in February, but highlights all of February so I can use the same formula for all of the other divisions, no matter the sort order of the table. Is this possible?
[image: Example Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. This worked (for finding the 3rd quartile):

`=QUARTILE(IF(Table6[$ February]*(Table6[Division]=C3) <> 0, Table6[$ February]*(Table6[Division]=C3)),3)`